# Episerver Find Wildcard search doesn't return expected results

Tags: episerver

Recently I've been experimenting with EPiServerFind, I'm trying to figure out how wildcard queries are used.

**I am encountering the following difficulty:**

One of my colleagues has set up a POC with EPiServerFind, sadly this only searches for the entire word. For example: If you search 'applepie' you will find the page but searching 'apple' or 'pie' won't find the page.
I've looked into wildcard queries to solve this, however I get unexpected results when I use them.

**Details**
Like I've pointed out earlier, whenever I query EPiServerFind I get only full word matches.

```
var basicSearch = _client.Search<IContent>()
    .For(q)
        .InFields(x => x.Name, x => x.SearchTitle(), x => x.SearchText())
        .InAllField()
    .ExcludeContainerPages()
    .ExcludeContentFolders()
    .ExcludeDeleted()
    .GetContentResult()
    .Select(CreateSearchHitViewModel)
    .Where(x => x != null);
```

I've used an article of Joel Abrahamsson to help me with the implementation of the wildcard query:

```
var wildcardSearch = _client.Search<IContent>()
    .WildCardQuery(String.Format("*{0}*", q), x => x.Name)
    .WildCardQuery(String.Format("*{0}*", q), x => x.SearchTitle())
    .WildCardQuery(String.Format("*{0}*", q), x => x.SearchText())
    .ExcludeContainerPages()
    .ExcludeContentFolders()
    .ExcludeDeleted()
    .GetContentResult()
    .Select(CreateSearchHitViewModel)
    .Where(x => x != null);
```

I've used this blog: http://joelabrahamsson.com/wildcard-queries-with-EPiServer-find/

Sadly I get unexpected results when I use this.
I get a few unrelated results but more of the relevant results are completely ignored.

I have no clue as to where this is failing and I hope someone can tell me.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As posted on EPiServer World it seems like you can do it by:

```
.For(searchTerm, q =>
{
q.Query = searchTerm + "*";
}).InField(x => x.Name)
```

And I guess you could add wildcard before the word as well.

Comment: I've added this code to my Episerver Find query to try to match using a wildcard but I still only receive whole word results.  Should this still work in newer versions?  I am using v11.1.0.3965

Comment: Works for me as well in EPiServer.Find v13.0.5

Comment: I know this is old, but I think I must say that it works for me too. But just as documentation says, it gets a lot of bad results. You search for a partial word it finds what you were aiming for. But then you search for the full word, like, the full name of the content, it does not find it anymore. In short, you are better without it.